Struggling with a simple Turbostream update for sidebar navigation
The turbo trigger link is just refreshing the page for my user show view.
I tried turbo_stream.replace & turbo_stream.update also pointed to the frame rightmaincontent but all that's happening is reloading the user show view which is the fallback part of the dance_journal method.
Am I overlooking something? All the tutorials and ChatGPT I'm seeing seems to show I'm setting this up correctly.
Also, I do have turbo frames setup for pagination on some other pages on my site so I'm sure that I have turbo installed correctly.
On my user show view I have a sidebar rendered via a partial (layouts/sidebar_content):
   <div class="sidebar-left">
      <%= render 'layouts/sidebar_content', user: @user %>
    </div>

Also on the user show view I have a section wrapped in the turbo frame rightmaincontent:
<%= turbo_frame_tag 'rightmaincontent' do %>
<div class="main-content">
Main Content Divs
</div>
<% end %>

Inside of the sidebar_content partial I have a link to the Dance Journal path:
 <%= link_to 'Your Dance Journal', dance_journal_user_path(@user), data: { turbo_frame: 'rightmaincontent' }, class: 'nav-link' %>

My dance journal partial is simple and as follows:
<div>
  <h3>Your Dance Journal</h3>
  <div class="container text-bg-light p-3 rounded">
    <h3>Your dance journal</h3>
    <div class="fs-6 fw-light">Keep track of your dance videos all in one place!</div>
    <br/>
    <p>Coming soon!</p>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>


And inside of my users controller I have a dance journal method with the following:
  def dance_journal
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update('rightmaincontent',
                                                partial: 'dance_journal',
                                                locals: { user: @user })
      end
      format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) } # Fallback for non-Turbo Stream requests
    end
  end 

Thanks in advance!

Is Turbo present on the page and working? Do you have any errors in the browser console which can expain it? Where is this link that you mentioned? Please also add an except from the Rails logs that show the incoming request.

The triggering link is on the user show view.
<%= link_to 'Your Dance Journal', dance_journal_user_path(@user), data: { turbo_frame: 'rightmaincontent' }, class: 'nav-link' %>
https://share.cleanshot.com/7Dx3vPJD the html inspect seems to be correct
in the rails log I'm getting
https://share.cleanshot.com/Rr88nsND

Here's current screen recording: https://share.cleanshot.com/Fx8PWMg9

Does the turboframe tag need to be a parent of the link? It looks like it's outside from the video.

So I was able to find that if I have the the link inside of the turbo frame tag 'rightmaintcontent' the page updates as expected.
So now I'm trying to figure out how I can trigger the same behaviour from a link that outside of the turbo frame tag in the sidebar navigation.
if you have any insights around that I'd appreciate it

Links send an HTML request, unless you specify otherwise, that's why format.html block is always called. If you want to do this with turbo frames then you have to wrap your response with a matching turbo frame:
<!-- _dance_journal.html.erb -->

<%= turbo_frame_tag "rightmaincontent" do %>
  <div>
    <h3>Your Dance Journal</h3>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>

and render it:
def dance_journal
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html do
      render partial: "dance_journal", locals: {user: @user}
    end
  end
end

Note that data-turbo-frame only tells turbo what frame you want to update and what frame to look for in a response, it is still an HTML request:
<%= link_to "Your Dance Journal", dance_journal_user_path(@user),
  class: "nav-link",
  data: {turbo_frame: "rightmaincontent"} %>


If you want to do this with a turbo stream then you have to add data-turbo-stream="true" to your link to make it a TURBO_STREAM request, in this case turbo frame is not needed:
<%= link_to "Your Dance Journal", dance_journal_user_path(@user),
  class: "nav-link",
  data: {turbo_stream: "true"} %>

<div id="rightmaincontent">
  <div class="main-content">
    Main Content Divs
  </div>
</div>

def dance_journal
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.turbo_stream do
      render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update(
        "rightmaincontent",
        partial: "dance_journal",
        locals: {user: @user})
    end
  end
end


https://share.cleanshot.com/fVDczSTg
This is redirecting directly to the partial https://share.cleanshot.com/X40XD873.

I made a change in the dance journal method and I'm getting the same error of navigating to another page
https://share.cleanshot.com/Fz2XQnnG

@Ogarocious you need to debug your Turbo setup, you probably have some errors in your javascript which prevent Turbo from loading. you can type Turbo in you browser console to verify. both setups work for me, i've double checked.

So I was able to find that if I have the the link inside of the turbo frame tag 'rightmaintcontent' the page updates as expected.
So now I'm trying to figure out how I can trigger the same behaviour from a link that outside of the turbo frame tag in the sidebar navigation.
if you have any insights around that I'd appreciate it

@Ogarocious data: {turbo_frame: "rightmaincontent"} should do it. still works fine for me. if you've misspelled the name of the frame, then it would navigate to the url, instead of updating the frame. you can log request.headers["Turbo-Frame"] to check what frame you're currently navigating.
